# Save/Download CKEditor text to local filesystem

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, ckeditor, local-storage

I am trying to save the text in CKEditor to local File system. Here's what I've done:

```
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){
  var htmlData = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
  blob = new Blob([htmlData], { type: 'text/html' });
  var data = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  $(this)
  .attr({
    'download': "test.html",
    'href': data
  });
});
```

All I'm trying to do here is download/save the text in `htmlData` to the local storage.

So when saveButton is clicked, this functionality currently works in Chrome, but not in IE or Mozilla. Does anyone know of a way to do this that is cross browser compatible. Any help would be appreciated.